# Inner function doesn't know variable defined in outer scope. Why?

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I'm trying to navigate through pages of an online dictionary. Here is my code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

var links = [];
function goToLink(linkName){
    nightmare
        .goto(linkName)
        .evaluate( () => {
            var href = document.querySelector("span.next a").href;
            links.push(href)
            return href;
        })
        .then((href) => {
            goToLink(href);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}

goToLink("http://lexicon.quranic-research.net/data/01_a/000_!.html");
```

I'm getting `Error: links is not defined`. Links is clearly defined at `var links = [];` but the inner function doesn't know about it. What is going on here?

Comment: I could imagine that `evaluate` stringifies the argument and evals it ina different context. Edit: see https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/89

Comment: You got it Felix. How do I accept a comment as the answer?

Comment: @FelixKling please add the comment as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `evaluate` callback is called in a different context and doesn't see `links`. What you can try to do is to pass it like this:

```
(...)
.evaluate( links => {
    var href = document.querySelector("span.next a").href;
    links.push(href)
    return href;
}, links)
(...)
```

`links` are the parameter of the callback. You have to pass it as a second parameter in the `evaluate` function.

Comment: Ah you can pass an argument. Cool.